# Displaying bitmap image in wpf datagrid defined at runtime

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Looking for some guidance as to how to display an image correctly in a wpf datagrid whose columns are defined at runtime, I can't define the columns in XAML.

My grids underlying collection contains an integer field that relates to a certain image.

I create a DataGridTextColumn column on my datagrid at runtime and bind it and set a converter.

```
Binding binding = new Binding("MyIntegerField");
binding.Converter = new Converters.IconIndexToImageConverter();
```

and my converter looks like this ;

```
public class IconIndexToImageConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            int imageIndex = (int)value;
            switch (imageIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    return Properties.Resources.clip;
```

but in my grid I don't see the image but see the type name, System.Drawing.Bitmap. All other bound fields are being displayed correctly.

I can see that the converter is being hit for this column, am I missing something on the binding?

Thanks....

Comment: Why would you even think a DataGrid**Text**Column is the right choice? Also, why a System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Comment: thanks for that...the image i'm surfacing is stored in the resource file as a System.Drawing.Bitmap. Should I be using a   DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: See answer; By the way, why can't you define it in XAML? Often people just think they can't because they do not have enough experience. In this case you could at least define the template for the column in XAML as a [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx).

Comment: thanks for that, the data grid columns are completed user definable so I can't define the column definitions in xmal, or at least i don't know how to. I appreciate that the template can exist in the xaml resources, thanks again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be using a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Yes, in combination with a template which instantiates an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control, which has your image as its `Source`, WPF works with the [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) base class, you will need to convert the `Bitmap`. Search SO, there already should be a question about that (the [`Interop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.aspx) class may be helpful).